# Is there a way to link specific words like linking an image?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to figure out the best way to link a proper name, that will be used a lot in my book. I am hoping to find an easy way to link to that proper name so that if I need to change that name in the future, all instances of that name will be updated as well. I am not looking for find/replace, becuase that would rely on me typing the name correctly every time. Ideally something like this: I create a master file with proper names, then everytime I want to use that name in my book I would link to that name in the master file. In two months when I change my mind on what that name should be, I go in to the master file and change that name and that updates throughout my book. Just like how if I use an image multiple times throughout a book, and I change that image later it will update on all the pages it was used on. Let me know how best to set this up, thanks!

Comment: I am aware of text-variables, but I am hoping for something more streamlined, i have over 100 of these names to deal with and text variables get kind of a pain to use once you have more than a couple.

Comment: So, you have a *way to link specific words* you just need to script a better interface for defining and inserting those words.

Comment: @user1754036 - yes, you are correct

Comment: Got it. So next decide how this new interface will work. Scripts could be used to make this new interface that will define, modify, and insert InDesign text variables in a way that works well for you. It's a full project where you'd need to gather requirements, draft specifications, then code script(s) accordingly. During that coding process, you may make some progress but run into a roadblock where you have a specific question about scripts that could be asked here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Nevertheless I'd propose to use the text variables. But you can handle them with the script:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var separator = ' > ';
var special_frame_name = 'VARIABLES';

make_list_variables();
change_variables();

function make_list_variables() {

    try {
        var frame = doc.textFrames.itemByName(special_frame_name);
        if (frame.parentStory.contents.indexOf(separator) > -1) return;
    } catch(e) {
        var frame = doc.pages[0].textFrames.add();
        frame.geometricBounds = [10, 10, 150, 50];
        frame.name = special_frame_name;
    }

    var variables = doc.textVariables.everyItem().getElements();
    var list = [];

    while(variables.length) {
        var variable = variables.pop();
        if (variable.variableType == VariableTypes.CUSTOM_TEXT_TYPE) {
            list.push(variable.name);
        }
    }

    frame.contents = list.sort().join('\r');
}

function change_variables() {

    try { var frame  = doc.textFrames.itemByName(special_frame_name) }
    catch(e) { return };

    var lines = frame.parentStory.contents.replace(/\r\r/g, '\r').split('\r');

    var variables_to_change = [];

    while(lines.length)  {
        var line = lines.shift();
        if (line.indexOf(separator) > -1) variables_to_change.push(line.split(separator));
    }

    while(variables_to_change.length) {
        var v = variables_to_change.pop();
        try {
            var variable = doc.textVariables.itemByName(v[0]);
            variable.name = v[1];
            variable.variableOptions.contents = v[1];
        } catch(e) { alert(e) }
    }

    frame.parentStory.contents = '';

    make_list_variables();
}
```

1. Create the custom text variables as per usual.

[image]

2. Run the script and it creates the text frame with names of all the variables.

[image]

3. In this frame you write (`old_name > new_name`) what name you want to change:

[image]

4. Run the script again and it changes the variables and updates the list of variables.

[image]